# Not displaying null strings in a spinner with the help of arrayadapter

Tags: android, xamarin

Im having a string array that contains a null character ,
i wish to not display this while continuing to use arrayadapter and not making a custom one.

this is the code

```
mxyz = view.FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.xyz);

List<string> xyzList = new List<string> ();
       xyzList = activity.set_xyz ();
       ArrayAdapter xyzAdapter = new ArrayAdapter (this.Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, xyzList);
       mxyz.Adapter = xyzAdapter;
```

how do i go about doing this?
thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you simply check for null strings while adding it in the list?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but im receiving those from the webservice and im not well versed in those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to clear the null string before using the list on the adapter, LINQ to Objects makes it really simple;

```
xyzList = activity.set_xyz ().Where(s => s != null).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried and this is the error im recieving " Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<bool>' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' "

Comment: Woah!! Sorry!!, big mistake, changing response now